# The correct way to reassess a probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm new to probabilities (as you might guess), so the best way I can explain my question is to do so by example. :)

Imagine a Galton Box which, through unexplained means (not important), distributes the probability of one's ball, dropped through the opening, equally among all possible landing zones. Meaning if a ball were dropped into it, it'd have just as likely a chance as ending up in the middle as it would ending up far off to the side.

Now imagine that this box has exactly 100 landing zones, 10% of which are colored blue, and 90% of which are colored red. However, I'm only 90% sure that the red ones do in fact allow balls into their landing zones, instead of deflecting them (the mechanics behind this don't matter) into a blue zone.

Suppose I drop one ball into the box and I see it ends up in a blue zone. Given that result, is the 90% probability that red zones allow balls into them reduced? By how much?

Sorry this was long-winded, that's the best I can explain it. Thanks for any answers.

Comment: In what way does this question vary from "I have a fair coin that has a 50% chance of landing heads each time I flip it.  I flip it and see that it landed heads.  Does that make tails any less likely to occur the next time I flip?"  Of course in the coin example, the outcome of one flip in no way affects future outcomes, and I am not seeing how your question differs.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking something more along the lines of "I have nine unfair coins which have both heads and tails with probability of heads 90% and one coin which has tails on both sides.  Given that I chose a coin uniformly at random and flipped it and saw that it was a tails, what is the probability that the coin I chose had a head on the other side?"

Comment: It depends then how you got the original figure of 90% sure that they don't deflect.  If this was based on billions of tests, seeing just one result of it landing in blue shouldn't affect it in the slightest.

Comment: Which sounds like my coin example in my second comment.  Is that then the correct interpretation of the problem?  If that is the case, then simply apply Baye's Theorem:  $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the difference between our examples is that the 9 unfair coins are still able to result in either head or tails. In my example, all of the red zones either deflect, or all of them don't, universally, as a rule. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The 9 unfair coins (out of ten) where both sides are possible correspond to the 90% certainity of having a machine where balls aren't deflected.  The 1 incredibly unfair doublesided coin where only one side is possible corresponds to the machines that deflect.  The fact that the coins with both sides *have* both sides corresponds to the fact that deflecting doesn't happen, and the coin with two of same side corresponds to deflecting occurring.  The probability of landing on heads for those coins with two sides corresponds to the number of red spaces there are to blue in your machines, etc...

Comment: Now that I think about it, yeah, that's exactly right! Thanks a lot for the help. I'll figure out Baye's theorem now and try to apply it, looks doable. If you post an official answer I'll make it this post's answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the comments, we rephrase the question into a more concrete example involving coins just for familiarity's sake:

> "I have nine unfair coins which have both heads and tails with probability of heads 90% and one coin which has tails on both sides. Given that I chose a coin uniformly at random and flipped it and saw that it was a tails, what is the probability that the coin I chose had a head on the other side?"

Let $A$ be the event we picked a coin with both a heads and a tails side.

Let $B$ be the event we flipped a tails.

From the problem statement, we are able to interpret several necessary probabilities directly, and more indirectly.  We then continue via Bayes' Theorem:

$$Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$$

> $Pr(B\mid A)=0.1,~Pr(A)=0.9,$ are given from the problem statement.  By law of total probability, $Pr(B)=Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)+Pr(B\mid A^c)Pr(A^c) = 0.1\cdot 0.9+1\cdot 0.1 = 0.19$ so...

$~$

> $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{0.1\cdot 0.9}{0.19}=\frac{0.09}{0.19}\approx 0.47$